# Connect Visual Studio solution to different Azure Devops projects

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops-server

We are using Azure Devops server to host our GIT projects. We also use Azure Devops Server for our development process. For historical reasons we have our repositories in one teams project and work with our tasks in another. It has never been any problems to be connected to those two different teams project until the release of Visual Studio 16.7. When I now connect to my GIT project I can't see the teams project where all my tasks are.

Is there anyone else that has a solution for this?

Comment: I finally solved the case. I'm not really sure how I did, but now it works...

Comment: If you meet this issue again, you may try my solution. If it can not solve your issue, you can feel free to open a new case.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following items:

1. Go to web portal, to see whether you can see the team project where all your tasks are.
2. If you can see the team project in web portal, check whether you use the same account to access the server in VS.
3. Close all Visual Studio instances, delete `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService`.
4. Clear Azure Devops server caches `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`.
5. Re-launch the VS and try to connect to server again.